# Is it possible to test thru ActivityUnitTestCase a org.holoeverywhere.Activity?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, android-holo-everywhere

I am coding my first ui test using *[holoEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/)*, I want to test a Activity which extends from *org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity* and I have this problem...

I tried to in the target app manifest this

And also in the manifest of the unit test project.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application instance isn't HoloEverywhere. Please sure that you extend class
>   android.test.mock.MockApplication from a
>   org.holoeverywhere.app.Application at
>   android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.onInit(_HoloActivity.java:449) at
>   android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.forceInit(_HoloActivity.java:207)
>   at org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:227) ......

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivityUnitTest extends
android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity> {
    private MainActivity activity;

    public MainActivityUnitTest () {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
      super.setUp();
      Context context = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();

      Intent intent = new Intent(context,
              MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent, null, null);
      activity = getActivity();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your mock application (which is created by the unit test) is not a HoloEverywhere application. Call setApplication before calling startActivity. This will replace the used android.test.mock.MockApplication with an org.HoloEverywhere.app.Application.

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception
{
   super.setUp();

   setApplication(new org.HoloEverywhere.app.Application());

   Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), DeclarerenActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent, null, null);
}
```